# PHP Methods Referencing Each Other causes PHP to return "No Data"

Tags: php, class, inheritance, methods, reference

PHP Methods Referencing Each Other causes PHP to return a page that says "No data received"

I am completly lost as to why this is happening since both methods belong to the same class...help please? : ()

--------- My Code ----- Simplified for Readability ----

```
<?php

/**
 * This is a simplified version of the situation that is causing me problems...
 * Each of theses methods needs to make a call to the other method
 */
class SomeClass {

  protected static function SomeProtectedStaticMethod() {
    SomeClass::SomePublicStaticMethod('some value for the call we make inside the class');
    return 'some return value';
  }

  public static function SomePublicStaticMethod($some_param) {
    $some_var = SomeClass::SomeProtectedStaticMethod();
    return $some_var . $some_param;
  }

}

$var = SomeClass::SomePublicStaticMethod('some value for the call we make outside the class');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should return a Stack Overflow error.

Answer (score 0):

This will cause an error like this:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of 'xxx' reached, aborting!`
```

Which is an error similar to `StackOverflow` because you are recursively calling the methods from each other and `stack` memory will be overflowed. This is an endless recursive method call (a loop of calling methods from each other that never ends) and should not work this way.

Make sure you have [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on so you can make sure what's going on. You may put following at the top of your script to turn on `error reporting`:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have generated an endless loop. It will naturally create a fatal error.

The error it generates is:

```
Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing **SomeClass::** with **self::**:

```
public static function SomePublicStaticMethod($some_param) {
   $some_var = self::SomeProtectedStaticMethod();
   return $some_var . $some_param;
}
```

but anyway your class is wrong, because your are calling again the public method from the protected, remove this call of the public method

```
 protected static function SomeProtectedStaticMethod() {
     return 'hello from protected method';
 }
```